# How can I get ordinal dates in Jekyll?

Tags: date, jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll, I would really like to have the date format as "2nd December 2012" — i.e. with the ordinal, rather than just "2 December 2012".

I see that there's an `ordinalize` function available in Ruby to do this, but I haven't had any luck combining it with Liquid and Jekyll.

How can I format dates as I would like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by writing the following Jekyll plugin, which I placed in the `_plugins` directory with an arbitrary name, e.g. `date.rb`:

```ruby
require 'date'
require 'facets/integer/ordinal'

module Jekyll
  module DateFilter
    def pretty(date)
      "#{date.strftime('%e').to_i.ordinalize} #{date.strftime('%B')} #{date.strftime('%Y')}"
    end  
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::DateFilter)
```

Then — having installed the `facets` Ruby gem — I was able to use `{{ post.date | pretty }}` in my site, and all was well.

Answer (score 6):

In Jekyll 3.8 or higher (for example with GitHub pages) you can just use the new `date_to_string` filter options and just write:

```
{{ page.date | date: "%I:%M %p on %A" }}
{{ page.date | date_to_string: "ordinal" }}
```

This will output: `12:23 PM on Friday 16th Jan 2015`

Answer (score 4):

For people using GitHub Pages:

If you're hosting your site on GitHub you won't be able to use modules (I believe GitHub run `jekyll build` with the `--safe` option which excludes modules), which means if you were to use Christopher's answer you'd have to build your site locally and then push the contents of the _site dir to GitHub.

Here's a solution to get an ordinal number/date just using Liquid which will allow you to use GitHub Pages + Jekyll in the usual way:

```
{% capture day %}{{ page.date | date: "%-d" }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture dayLastTwoDigits %}{{ day | modulo: 100 }}{% endcapture %}
{% if dayLastTwoDigits >= "11" and dayLastTwoDigits <= "13" %}
    {% assign ordinal = "th" %}
{% else %}
    {% capture dayLastDigit %}{{ day | modulo: 10 }}{% endcapture %}
    {% case dayLastDigit %}
        {% when "1" %}
            {% assign ordinal = "st" %}
        {% when "2" %}
            {% assign ordinal = "nd" %}
        {% when "3" %}
            {% assign ordinal = "rd" %}
        {% else %}
            {% assign ordinal = "th" %}
    {% endcase %}
{% endif %}
{% capture ordinalDay %}{{ day | append: ordinal }}{% endcapture %}
<p class="post-meta">{{ page.date | date: "%I:%M %p on %A" }} {{ ordinalDay }} {{ page.date | date: "of %b, %Y" }}{% if page.author %} • {{ page.author }}{% endif %}{% if page.meta %} • {{ page.meta }}{% endif %}</p>
```

This will output something like:

`12:23 PM on Friday 16th of Jan, 2015`

Comment: You would need to add additional logic to handle the numbers 11 to 13.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherOrr, silly me. All fixed and edited above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an entirely Liquid answer, you can do the following:

1. Create an include file, say for example: ordinalsuffix.html
2. Put the following code into that file:

---

```
{% assign numbertoordinal = (numbertoordinal | default: 0) | plus: 0 | modulo: 100 %}
{% assign ordinalresult = "th" %}

{% case numbertoordinal %}
    {% when 1 or 21 or 31 or 41 or 51 or 61 or 71 or 81 or 91 %}
    {% assign ordinalresult = "st" %}
    {% when 2 or 22 or 32 or 42 or 52 or 62 or 72 or 82 or 92 %}
    {% assign ordinalresult = "nd" %}
    {% when 3 or 23 or 33 or 43 or 53 or 63 or 73 or 83 or 93 %}
    {% assign ordinalresult = "rd" %}
{% endcase %}
```

---

3. Then you can essentially call it like a function, like such:

---

```
{% assign numbertoordinal = 101 %}
{% include ordinalsuffix.html %}
{% assign result = numbertoordinal | append: ordinalresult %}
```

---

Of course, you'll need to expand this for it to output fully formatted dates. But if you want to know what ordinal suffix any arbitrary number has, this is a reasonably clean answer.